# Give Image as Store view name

Tags: magento-1.9, backend, store-view

Once we go For `System > Mange Stores` > If we click on any store view, it will display as below image :

[image]

what name we give here , we are  displaying in frontend.

i want to display **image** in Name textfield. how we can achieve this ?

Comment: Are you want to show flag image instead of store view name?

Comment: @aman_uni we want to show currency image

Comment: Ok hold on i will send you solution this should work for you

Comment: https://www.atwix.com/magento/replace-language-selector-flag-icons/

Comment: Follow above link that will help you to add images fot your store

Comment: @aman_uni thanks for link, but i want to display currency symbols, not flag icons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very bad idea to change **Name** field to *image* from *text*.
Bcoz of this field are ***called at several places*** as text file at magento system.

So if you will **want change this image** then need t*o lot of customizations and may be create lot of issues.*   That why i suggest to avoid this.

A solution, ***instead of  changing name field type*** create a new field at `core_store`. by a magento  custom module installer.